# What is the use of #define macros inside of an array initialization in C?

Tags: c, arrays, syntax, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Can someone explain what the syntax shown below in C is? My question is about the (#define)'s inside the declaration of `qdata`. They seem to be markers.

This might be useful information: `qdata` stores a bunch of constants that are used throughout the code.

For completeness, this piece of code can be found in `const.c` in this [repository](https://github.com/pq-crystals/kyber/blob/master/avx2/consts.c).

```
const uint16_t qdata[928] __attribute__((aligned(32))) = {
#define _16XQ 0
  Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q,

#define _16XQINV 16
  QINV, QINV, QINV, QINV, QINV, QINV, QINV, QINV,
  QINV, QINV, QINV, QINV, QINV, QINV, QINV, QINV,

#define _16XV 32
  V, V, V, V, V, V, V, V, V, V, V, V, V, V, V, V,

#define _16XFLO 48
  FLO, FLO, FLO, FLO, FLO, FLO, FLO, FLO,
  FLO, FLO, FLO, FLO, FLO, FLO, FLO, FLO,

#define _16XFHI 64
  FHI, FHI, FHI, FHI, FHI, FHI, FHI, FHI,
  FHI, FHI, FHI, FHI, FHI, FHI, FHI, FHI,

#define _16XMONTSQLO 80
  MONTSQLO, MONTSQLO, MONTSQLO, MONTSQLO,
  MONTSQLO, MONTSQLO, MONTSQLO, MONTSQLO,
  MONTSQLO, MONTSQLO, MONTSQLO, MONTSQLO,
  MONTSQLO, MONTSQLO, MONTSQLO, MONTSQLO,

#define _16XMONTSQHI 96
  MONTSQHI, MONTSQHI, MONTSQHI, MONTSQHI,
  MONTSQHI, MONTSQHI, MONTSQHI, MONTSQHI,
  MONTSQHI, MONTSQHI, MONTSQHI, MONTSQHI,
  MONTSQHI, MONTSQHI, MONTSQHI, MONTSQHI,

#define _16XMASK 112
  MASK, MASK, MASK, MASK, MASK, MASK, MASK, MASK,
  MASK, MASK, MASK, MASK, MASK, MASK, MASK, MASK,

#define _ZETAS_EXP 128
  31499, 31499,  2571,  2571, 14746, 14746,  2970,  2970,
  13525, 13525, 13525, 13525, 13525, 13525, 13525, 13525,
  53134, 53134, 53134, 53134, 53134, 53134, 53134, 53134,
   1493,  1493,  1493,  1493,  1493,  1493,  1493,  1493,
   1422,  1422,  1422,  1422,  1422,  1422,  1422,  1422,
  44630, 44630, 44630, 44630, 27758, 27758, 27758, 27758,
  61737, 61737, 61737, 61737, 49846, 49846, 49846, 49846,
   3158,  3158,  3158,  3158,   622,   622,   622,   622,
   1577,  1577,  1577,  1577,   182,   182,   182,   182,
  59709, 59709, 17364, 17364, 39176, 39176, 36479, 36479,
   5572,  5572, 64434, 64434, 21439, 21439, 39295, 39295,
    573,   573,  2004,  2004,   264,   264,   383,   383,
   2500,  2500,  1458,  1458,  1727,  1727,  3199,  3199,
  59847, 59020,  1497, 30967, 41972, 20179, 20711, 25081,
  52740, 26617, 16065, 53095,  9135, 64887, 39550, 27837,
   1223,   652,  2777,  1015,  2036,  1491,  3047,  1785,
    516,  3321,  3009,  2663,  1711,  2167,   126,  1469,
  65202, 54059, 33310, 20494, 37798,   945, 50654,  6182,
  32011, 10631, 29176, 36775, 47051, 17561, 51106, 60261,
   2226,   555,  2078,  1550,   422,   177,  3038,  1574,
   3083,  1159,  2552,  2727,  1739,  2457,   418,  3173,
  11182, 13387, 51303, 43881, 13131, 60950, 23093,  5493,
  33034, 30318, 46795, 12639, 20100, 18525, 19529, 52918,
    430,   843,   871,   105,   587,  3094,  2869,  1653,
    778,  3182,  1483,  1119,   644,   349,   329,  3254,
    788,   788,  1812,  1812, 28191, 28191, 28191, 28191,
  28191, 28191, 28191, 28191, 48842, 48842, 48842, 48842,
  48842, 48842, 48842, 48842,   287,   287,   287,   287,
    287,   287,   287,   287,   202,   202,   202,   202,
    202,   202,   202,   202, 10690, 10690, 10690, 10690,
   1359,  1359,  1359,  1359, 54335, 54335, 54335, 54335,
  31164, 31164, 31164, 31164,   962,   962,   962,   962,
   2127,  2127,  2127,  2127,  1855,  1855,  1855,  1855,
   1468,  1468,  1468,  1468, 37464, 37464, 24313, 24313,
  55004, 55004,  8800,  8800, 18427, 18427,  8859,  8859,
  26676, 26676, 49374, 49374,  2648,  2648,  1017,  1017,
    732,   732,   608,   608,  1787,  1787,   411,   411,
   3124,  3124,  1758,  1758, 19884, 37287, 49650, 56638,
  37227,  9076, 35338, 18250, 13427, 14017, 36381, 52780,
  16832,  4312, 41381, 47622,  2476,  3239,  3058,   830,
    107,  1908,  3082,  2378,  2931,   961,  1821,  2604,
    448,  2264,   677,  2054, 34353, 25435, 58154, 24392,
  44610, 10946, 24215, 16990, 10336, 57603, 43035, 10907,
  31637, 28644, 23998, 48114,   817,   603,  1322,  1864,
   2114,  1218,  2455,  2142,  2144,  2051,  1819,  2459,
   3221,   996,   958,  1522, 20297,  2146, 15356, 33152,
  59257, 50634, 54492, 14470, 44039, 45338, 23211, 48094,
  41677, 45279,  7757, 23132,  1097,   610,  2044,   384,
   3193,  1994,   220,  1670,  1799,   794,  2475,   478,
   3021,   991,  1869,  1628,     0,     0,     0,     0,

#define _ZETAS_INV_EXP 528
  42405, 57780, 20258, 23860, 17443, 42326, 20199, 21498,
  51067, 11045, 14903,  6280, 32385, 50181, 63391, 45240,
   1701,  1460,  2338,   308,  2851,   854,  2535,  1530,
   1659,  3109,  1335,   136,  2945,  1285,  2719,  2232,
  17423, 41539, 36893, 33900, 54630, 22502,  7934, 55201,
  48547, 41322, 54591, 20927, 41145,  7383, 40102, 31184,
   1807,  2371,  2333,   108,   870,  1510,  1278,  1185,
   1187,   874,  2111,  1215,  1465,  2007,  2726,  2512,
  17915, 24156, 61225, 48705, 12757, 29156, 51520, 52110,
  47287, 30199, 56461, 28310,  8899, 15887, 28250, 45653,
   1275,  2652,  1065,  2881,   725,  1508,  2368,   398,
    951,   247,  1421,  3222,  2499,   271,    90,   853,
  16163, 16163, 38861, 38861, 56678, 56678, 47110, 47110,
  56737, 56737, 10533, 10533, 41224, 41224, 28073, 28073,
   1571,  1571,   205,   205,  2918,  2918,  1542,  1542,
   2721,  2721,  2597,  2597,  2312,  2312,   681,   681,
  34373, 34373, 34373, 34373, 11202, 11202, 11202, 11202,
  64178, 64178, 64178, 64178, 54847, 54847, 54847, 54847,
   1861,  1861,  1861,  1861,  1474,  1474,  1474,  1474,
   1202,  1202,  1202,  1202,  2367,  2367,  2367,  2367,
  16695, 16695, 16695, 16695, 16695, 16695, 16695, 16695,
  37346, 37346, 37346, 37346, 37346, 37346, 37346, 37346,
   3127,  3127,  3127,  3127,  3127,  3127,  3127,  3127,
   3042,  3042,  3042,  3042,  3042,  3042,  3042,  3042,
  64749, 64749,  1517,  1517, 12619, 46008, 47012, 45437,
  52898, 18742, 35219, 32503, 60044, 42444,  4587, 52406,
  21656, 14234, 52150, 54355,    75,  3000,  2980,  2685,
   2210,  1846,   147,  2551,  1676,   460,   235,  2742,
   3224,  2458,  2486,  2899,  5276, 14431, 47976, 18486,
  28762, 36361, 54906, 33526, 59355, 14883, 64592, 27739,
  45043, 32227, 11478,   335,   156,  2911,   872,  1590,
    602,   777,  2170,   246,  1755,   291,  3152,  2907,
   1779,  1251,  2774,  1103, 37700, 25987,   650, 56402,
  12442, 49472, 38920, 12797, 40456, 44826, 45358, 23565,
  34570, 64040,  6517,  5690,  1860,  3203,  1162,  1618,
    666,   320,     8,  2813,  1544,   282,  1838,  1293,
   2314,   552,  2677,  2106, 26242, 26242, 44098, 44098,
   1103,  1103, 59965, 59965, 29058, 29058, 26361, 26361,
  48173, 48173,  5828,  5828,   130,   130,  1602,  1602,
   1871,  1871,   829,   829,  2946,  2946,  3065,  3065,
   1325,  1325,  2756,  2756, 15691, 15691, 15691, 15691,
   3800,  3800,  3800,  3800, 37779, 37779, 37779, 37779,
  20907, 20907, 20907, 20907,  3147,  3147,  3147,  3147,
   1752,  1752,  1752,  1752,  2707,  2707,  2707,  2707,
    171,   171,   171,   171, 12403, 12403, 12403, 12403,
  12403, 12403, 12403, 12403, 52012, 52012, 52012, 52012,
  52012, 52012, 52012, 52012,  1907,  1907,  1907,  1907,
   1907,  1907,  1907,  1907,  1836,  1836,  1836,  1836,
   1836,  1836,  1836,  1836, 50791, 50791,   359,   359,
  60300, 60300,  1932,  1932,     0,     0,     0,     0
};
```

Comment: Looks to me like the macros are defining the element offsets for each of the following block of data.

Comment: The defines can't and don't affect the array in any way and are basically non-conflicting redefinitions of macros that are already present. That could serve as an assertion of a macro value (the compiler must issue a diagnostic only if the macro redefinition is a conflicting one).

Comment: "non-conflicting redefinitions of macros that are already present" in consts.h in that repository (to clarify comment by @PSkocik )